# Understanding of Python Class and base Class

Tags: python

Let's say we have an instantiation

```
client = PiHttpClient("192.168.1.234")
# RPi native GPIO
gpio = NativeGPIO(client)
gpio.setFunction(25, "out")
state = True
```

And from the clients.py code I have

```
class PiMixedClient():
    def __init__(self, host, port=8000, coap=5683):
    def sendRequest(self, method, uri):

class PiHttpClient(PiMixedClient):
    def __init__(self, host, port=8000):
        PiMixedClient.__init__(self, host, port, -1)
class NativeGPIO(GPIO):
    def __init__(self, client):
        RESTAPI.__init__(self, client, "/GPIO")

class GPIO(Device):
    def __init__(self, client, name):
        Device.__init__(self, client, name, "digital")

    def getFunction(self, channel):
        return self.sendRequest("GET", "/%d/function" % channel)

    def setFunction(self, channel, func):
        return self.sendRequest("POST", "/%d/function/%s" % (channel, func))

class Device(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, client, name, category):
        RESTAPI.__init__(self, client, "/devices/" + name + "/" + category)

class RESTAPI():
    def __init__(self, client, path):
        self.client = client
        self.path = path

    def sendRequest(self, method, path):
        return self.client.sendRequest(method, self.path + path)
```

1. So, from the above when it does PiHttpClient("192.168.1.234")  the host="192.168.1.234", right? but the *init*(self,host, port=8000) looks for self, host. I didn't see self being passed in as argument.
2. then inside PiMixedClient, because PiHttpClient extending PiMixedClient, then its host and self should be as the same as PiMixedClient
3. then gpio=NativeGPIO(client)    again inside the *init* of NativeGPIO  _*init*(self, client),  from the calling function I do not need to supply the self?
4. so when extending to lowest level it become RESTAPI base class, its sendRequest method is from client which is from the PiMixedClient class's sendRequest?

Comment: please correct your indentation..

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes - a python method always gets self as first argument, you might want to take a look at the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) on classes.
2. Yes
3. -
4. No. You do not need to manually suply self if you create an instance of the class (you do if you want to override the init method)
5. Yes

But really, take a look at the python docs, they are pretty good.